# Convert HTML <dl> into a nested array by using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list-definition

I'm looking for a way to convert a HTML definition list `<dl>` into a nested array with PHP.

Example list:

```
<dl>
  <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>A1</dd>
  <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>B1</dd>
    <dd>B2</dd>
</dl>
```

Preferred output:

```
[ 'A' => ['A1'], 'B' => ['B1', 'B2'] ]
```

I already found a jQuery solution ([Turning HTML <dl> into a nested JavaScript array with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175208/turning-html-dl-into-a-nested-javascript-array-with-jquery)) which works (almost) like I want it to be BUT I'm working on a jQuery-less project and would therefor like to do the same with just PHP.

I've also already looked at PHP functions like XML_PARSE_INTO_STRUCT but unfortunately I don't get to a working solution with it.

So I'm currently stuck with my search. Can anyone give me a pointer into the right direction?

Comment: Could read in the HTML file using file_get_contents, then use preg_match to grab everything from dl to /dl, use that and build from there

Comment: Then use vanilla javascript! JQuery is not a seperate language, it is a javascript framework remember

Comment: @clearshot66 I'm using the PHP Simple HTML DOM script to extract my source so I've the <dl> to </dl> code already isolated.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah you're 100% right, native Javascript is indeed an option too! So funny how I always overlook that... guess it must be because I'm not overly into Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do it using pure JS without using jQuery.

```
        function dlToObject(dl){
            if(!dl){
                return {};
            }

            var elems  = dl.querySelectorAll('dl dt, dl dd'),
                parent = '',
                result = {};

            for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
                var element = elems[i];

                if(element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'dt'){
                    parent = element.innerText;
                    result[parent] = [];
                }else{
                    result[parent].push(element.innerText)
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        var myDl = document.querySelector('dl');

        console.log(dlToObject(myDl)); //{'A':['A1'],'B':['B1', 'B2']}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! That said I'm currently also looking into a pure PHP solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803228/simple-html-dom-how-get-dt-dd-elements-to-array as a PHP solution still holds my preference.